# Ansible-playbook issue using pexpect module

Tags: ansible, pexpect

Some one can help with this issue please.
With python2  the interpreter can't use pexpect module :( at all.
Using python3 i got the error.

I tried to work arrond by installing pexpect module, without success

=======================================

PIP modules:

> [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]# pip show pexpect DEPRECATION:
> Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please
> upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0
> will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about
> Python 2 support in pip can be found at
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. Name: pexpect
> Version: 3.3 Summary: Pexpect allows easy control of interactive
> console applications. Home-page: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/
> Author: Noah Spurrier; Thomas Kluyver; Jeff Quast Author-email:
> noah@noah.org; thomas@kluyver.me.uk; contact@jeffquast.com License:
> ISC license Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages Requires:
> Required-by: [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]# pip-3 show pexpect
> Name: pexpect Version: 4.8.0 Summary: Pexpect allows easy control of
> interactive console applications. Home-page:
> https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/ Author: Noah Spurrier; Thomas Kluyver;
> Jeff Quast Author-email: noah@noah.org, thomas@kluyver.me.uk,
> contact@jeffquast.com License: ISC license Location:
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages Requires: ptyprocess
> [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]# [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]#
> [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]# [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]#
> [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]# pip-3 list DEPRECATION: The default
> format will switch to columns in the future. You can use
> --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning. ansible
> (2.9.6) ansible-autodoc (0.5.3) cffi (1.14.0) cryptography (2.8)
> Jinja2 (2.11.1) MarkupSafe (1.1.1) pexpect (4.8.0) pip (9.0.3)
> ptyprocess (0.7.0) pycparser (2.20) PyYAML (5.3.1) rpm (4.11.3)
> setuptools (39.2.0) six (1.14.0) [root@localhost ansible_epo_test]#

ANSIBLE CODE:

```
- name: "Install the patch .jar "
  expect:
    command: "/opt/ibm/cics/bin/TXSeriesFixInstaller.sh {{patch_name}}"
    responses:
      '.*Press 1 for Installation, 2 to Usage or 3 to Cancel.*': '1'
      '.*Do you want to proceed?.*': 'y'
    echo: yes
    chdir: "{{installation_dir}}/{{product_name}}"
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  register: install_patch_execution
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: '".jar" in patch_name'
```

OUTPUT:

```
<172.18.19.182> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<172.18.19.182> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/1106f609b6 172.18.19.182 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996="` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.18.19.182> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996=/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py
<172.18.19.182> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-29887paj4oih0/tmplewouwv_ TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py
<172.18.19.182> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/1106f609b6 '[172.18.19.182]'
<172.18.19.182> (0, b'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-29887paj4oih0/tmplewouwv_ /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py\n', b'')
<172.18.19.182> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<172.18.19.182> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/1106f609b6 172.18.19.182 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/ /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.18.19.182> (0, b'', b'')
<172.18.19.182> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<172.18.19.182> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/1106f609b6 -tt 172.18.19.182 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-bikuwrrsbrvqqqpnsttxannmfqpdgptf ; /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<172.18.19.182> (1, b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py", line 40, in invoke_module\r\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name=\'ansible.modules.commands.expect\', init_globals=None, run_name=\'__main__\', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module\r\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\r\n  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\r\n  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible_expect_payload_bxa5j6_h/ansible_expect_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py", line 246, in <module>\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible_expect_payload_bxa5j6_h/ansible_expect_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py", line 205, in main\r\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/run.py", line 100, in run\r\n    cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs)\r\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__\r\n    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)\r\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 304, in _spawn\r\n    cwd=self.cwd, **kwargs)\r\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 315, in _spawnpty\r\n    return ptyprocess.PtyProcess.spawn(args, **kwargs)\r\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py", line 336, in spawn\r\n    raise exception\r\nOSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error\r\n', b'Shared connection to 172.18.19.182 closed.\r\n')
<172.18.19.182> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 172.18.19.182 closed.
<172.18.19.182> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<172.18.19.182> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/1106f609b6 172.18.19.182 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.18.19.182> (0, b'', b'')
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.commands.expect', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_expect_payload_bxa5j6_h/ansible_expect_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py", line 246, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_expect_payload_bxa5j6_h/ansible_expect_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py", line 205, in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/run.py", line 100, in run
    cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 304, in _spawn
    cwd=self.cwd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 315, in _spawnpty
    return ptyprocess.PtyProcess.spawn(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py", line 336, in spawn
    raise exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
fatal: [172.18.19.182]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.18.19.182 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible-tmp-1630657688.0494435-190630914787996/AnsiballZ_expect.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\r\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.commands.expect', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\r\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_expect_payload_bxa5j6_h/ansible_expect_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py\", line 246, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_expect_payload_bxa5j6_h/ansible_expect_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py\", line 205, in main\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/run.py\", line 100, in run\r\n    cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs)\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py\", line 205, in __init__\r\n    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py\", line 304, in _spawn\r\n    cwd=self.cwd, **kwargs)\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py\", line 315, in _spawnpty\r\n    return ptyprocess.PtyProcess.spawn(args, **kwargs)\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py\", line 336, in spawn\r\n    raise exception\r\nOSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
...ignoring
```

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

###### The error encontred is regarding shebang #!/usr... in the script "/opt/ibm/cics/bin/TXSeriesFixInstaller.sh"

###### The script is provided by IBM so i can't fix it myself, so in order to fix that i used "ksh /opt/ibm/cics/bin/TXSeriesFixInstaller.sh"